# pandas extract two capture groups get all

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am just not quite getting this regex. Can someone help please.

Start with this:

```
s = pd.Series(['Up to £48,000 a year', '£50,000 - £60,000 a year', '£11.86 - £14.69 an hour'])

0        Up to £48,000 a year
1    £50,000 - £60,000 a year
2     £11.86 - £14.69 an hour
3                   no salary
```

First try (missing £48,000)

```
s = pd.Series(['Up to £48,000 a year', '£50,000 - £60,000 a year', '£11.86 - £14.69 an hour', 'no salary'])
s.str.extract(r'(\d\d[.,]\d\d\d?).*(\d\d[.,]\d\d\d?)')

    0       1
0   NaN     NaN
1   50,000  60,000
2   11.86   14.69
3   NaN     NaN
```

Second try (missing all in second column)

```
s = pd.Series(['Up to £48,000 a year', '£50,000 - £60,000 a year', '£11.86 - £14.69 an hour', 'no salary'])
s.str.extract(r'(\d\d[.,]\d\d\d?).*(\d\d[.,]\d\d\d?)?')

    0       1
0   48,000  NaN
1   50,000  NaN
2   11.86   NaN
3   NaN     NaN
```

How do I get this?

```
    0       1
0   48,000  NaN
1   50,000  60,000
2   11.86   14.69
3   NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
s.str.findall(r'(?:£)(\d+[,.]\d+)').apply(pd.Series)
>>>
    0       1
0   48,000  NaN
1   50,000  60,000
2   11.86   14.69
3   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Nice solution, I will use your solution as my dataset is not to large. But I think @Wiktor Stribiżew solution might be better for a larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `replace` and `split`:

```py
s.str.replace(r'.*?\b(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)(?:.*?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*))?.*|.+', r'\1 \2', regex=True).str.split(expand=True)
```

Output:

```py
        0       1
0  48,000    None
1  50,000  60,000
2   11.86   14.69
3    None    None
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhyaEt/2). *Details*:

- `.*?\b(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)(?:.*?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*))?.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (`.*?`), then a word boundary (`\b`), then Group 1 - one or more digits + zero or more occurrences of a `.` or `,` and one or more digits after it, then an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (`.*?`) and then Group 2 - one or more digits + zero or more occurrences of a `.` or `,` and one or more digits after it, and then the rest of the line (`.*`)
- `|` - or
- `.+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible. Use `^.*$` instead if the lines can be empty, and you still need to produce to `NaN`s in two columns.

Comment: Nice solution without using ```apply```.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Series.str.extractall`.

It is possible to find all capturing group specified in the RegEx pattern and reshape after using `unstack`.

```
s.str.extractall(r'([.\d][.,\d]*)').unstack()
```

```
match       0       1
0      48,000     NaN
1      50,000  60,000
2       11.86   14.69
```

You can test it using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZsP2Td/1)

Comment: This works but the problem I have found with extractall is that I lose rows when both column are NaN. I will tweak the question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

A not very elegant approach that does this specific job

```
vals = s.values
rgx = '[A-Za-z£-]' # instead of finding the digits, get rid of eerything else
vals = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(rgx,'',x).strip(), vals))
vals = list(map(lambda x: re.split(r'\s+',x),vals))
vals = list(map(lambda x: x if len(x) == 2 else [x[0],np.NAN],vals))
s = pd.DataFrame(vals)
print(s)

        0       1
0  48,000     NaN
1  50,000  60,000
2   11.86   14.69
```

Or something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values)
rgx = '[A-Za-z£-]'
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(rgx,'', regex = True)
df = df[0].str.split(r'\s+',expand = True)
df.pop(df.columns[-1])
```

None of them are ideal for a more general case, but if it works...